# Difference between `reproject_match` and `interp_like`

Tags: rioxarray, xarray

I'm pretty new to GIS and I'm trying to understand the difference between the interpolation done with [`rioxarray` `reproject_match`](https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/reproject_match.html#Example---Reproject-Match-(For-Raster-Calculations/Stacking)) and [`xarray` `interp_like`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/interpolation.html#multi-dimensional-interpolation).

Assuming I have two rasters `da1` and `da2` with same CRS but different dimensions:

```py
import rioxarray
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

np.random.seed(3)

da1 = xr.DataArray(
    np.random.rand(2, 3),
    [
        ('y', [-30.25, -30.3]),
        ('x', [149.8 , 149.85, 149.9])
    ]
)
da1 = da1.rio.write_crs(4326)

da2 = xr.DataArray(
    np.random.rand(4, 11),
    [
        ('y', [-30.25733604, -30.26550543, -30.27367483, -30.28184423]),
        ('x', [149.82193392, 149.83010332, 149.83827272, 149.84644211,
        149.85461151, 149.86278091, 149.87095031, 149.87911971,
        149.8872891 , 149.8954585 , 149.9036279 ])
    ]
)
da2 = da2.rio.write_crs(4326)
```

Then I calculated the extrapolated `da1` with the two functions:

```py
r_reproject_match = (
    da1.rio.reproject_match(da2)
    .assign_coords({"x": da2.x, "y": da2.y})
)
r_interp_like = da1.interp_like(da2)
```

and compare the differences:

```py
r_reproject_match.where(r_reproject_match != r_interp_like).plot()
```

[image]

There are differences in many pixels:

```py
r_reproject_match.where(
    r_reproject_match == r_interp_like,
    np.abs(r_reproject_match - r_interp_like)
).plot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

xarray uses scipy to do the interpolation with the default linear method (http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.interp_like.html#xarray.Dataset.interp_like).

Why use `interp_like`? It is a nice solution if your datasets have the same CRS and you don't want to install GDAL.

rioxarray uses GDAL to do the interpolation with the default nearest method.

Why use `reproject_match`? It is useful if you need to convert your dataset from one CRS to match the other. Also, there are many more interpolation options available.